# Switching Scenes and creating menus in JAVA FX

Tags: javafx-8

I have two sperate JAVA fx games such as a card game and snake game. How would I start or what should I research to make a menu that would allow me to choose which game to play and all in one zip file or program?? Kinda like a game chooser and then the user can play the game they want or exit when done and play the other game in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You just code your particular games. Each of them can be displayed in a pane with respective controller, with all its sub modules. To change the game, you just need to change respective pane.

The master controller controls choosing game, load game, unload game, exit game...
snakeController controls snake game,
cardController controls card game.

There might be different approaches.

Hope this helps